# Как передать методы Фрагмента во ViewModel?

Tags: java, android, viewmodel

Мой фрагмент реализует методы интрефейса. Мне нужно передать эти методы в `ViewModel`

Методы интерфейса реализованные во Фрагменте:

```
@Override
public Note newNoteForEquals() {
    Note newNoteForEquals = new Note();
    newNoteForEquals.setId(note.getId());
    newNoteForEquals.setTitle(editTextTitle.getText().toString());
    newNoteForEquals.setDescription(editTextDescription.getText().toString());
    newNoteForEquals.setDate(note.getDate());
    return newNoteForEquals;
}

@Override
public String getTitleFromEditText() {
    return editTextTitle.getText().toString();
}

@Override
public String getDescriptionFromEditText() {
    return editTextTitle.getText().toString();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            if (note != null) {
                if (!(newNoteForEquals().equals(startNote()))) {
                    viewModelCreateNote.createAlertDialog(getContext());
                } else {
                    goHome();
                }
            } else {
                goHome();
            }
        }
   };
   requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(getViewLifecycleOwner(), callback);
}

@Override
public void goHome() {
    Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(R.id.home_dest);
}
```

Метод во `ViewModel`, где необходимо задействовать методы из фрагмента.
Я попытался реализовать это передав через конструктор `ViewModel` интерфейс фрагмента, но получил `RuntimeExeption`.

```
ICreateNoteView view;

private CreateNoteViewModel(ICreateNoteView view) {
    this.view = view;
}

public void createAlertDialog(final Context context) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
          .setMessage(R.string.save_the_changes)
          .setCancelable(false)
          .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  if (validation(view.getTitleFromEditText(),
                     view.getDescriptionFromEditText())) {
                     updateNote(view.newNoteForEquals());
                     view.goHome();
                  } else {
                     view.showMsgFailValid();
                  }
              }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           view.goHome();
       }
    }).create().show();
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Наследование фрагмента от интерфейса и вызов методов со стороны бизнес-логики подразумевает использование подхода MVP.
Использование `ViewModel` подразумевает использование подхода MVVM, где интерфейсами и не пахнет. В MVVM  обычно отдают фрагментам / активностям команды с помощью `LiveData`. [Обучалка](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/525-urok-2-livedata.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того, что если ваша `ViewModel` знает о каком-то интерфейсе `View`, то это уже не `ViewModel`, а скорее всего `Presenter`.

В чем принципиальная разница между **MVP** и **MVVM** подходом? Разница в том, что `Presenter` знает о существовании `View` (как минимум ее интерфейса), а ViewModel ничего не знает о существовании каких-либо `View`.

Взаимодействие между фрагментом и `ViewModel` проходит по принципу подписки. Т.е. фрагмент знает о существовании `ViewModel` и подписывается на ее изменения. Когда какие-либо изменения проходят в `ViewModel`, она постит свои изменения и все подписчики реагируют на них. Тем самым получается, что у нас может существовать 1 `ViewModel` и к примеру 10 фрагментов подписанных на нее.

Вот небольшой пример:

```
class TestViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> messageLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public LiveData<String> getMessageLiveData() {
        return messageLiveData;
    }

    public void getMessage() {
        // remote request
        messageLiveData.postValue("Message");
    }
}


class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    
    // я тут пропустил ее инициализацию. Тут вы уже выберете свой способ, либо инжектить через DI либо через стандартную фабрику
    private TestViewModel testViewModel; 
    
    // some code

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        testViewModel.getMessageLiveData().observe(this, this::handleMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        testViewModel.getMessage();
    }

    private void handleMessage(String message) {
        // some interraction with message
    }
}
```

В этом примере ваша `ViewModel` не знает о своих подписчиках. Она постит свои данные в никуда, а подписчики сами решают как это обработать. Всякий раз когда во `ViewModel` будет изменена `messageLiveData` будет вызываться метод observe в `View` и там же вы можете обрабатывать изменение ваших данных.

Если же вам интересно все же `MVP` то я рекомендую вас посмотреть на эти 2 урока. [Простой пример](https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/493-mvp-dlja-nachinajuschih-bez-bibliotek-i-interfejsov.html) и [более сложный пример](https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/473-mvp-na-primere-jekrana-s-pin-kodom.html).

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение, Вы мне очень помогли!